# ArgoCD failing to sync resource with metav1.Duration

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

Hi I'm trying to deploy cert-manager.io/Certificate resource through argoCD. The manifest for this resource has the below field

```
spec:
  duration: 4567h
```

After the resource is applied to cluster by argoCD, ClusterIssuer mutates the above resource resulting in

```
spec:
  duration: 4567h0m0s
```

After looking through clusterIssuer code, it looks like its unmarshalling above resource as `metav1.Duration` due to which mutation happens.

Due to this the argoApplication is always OutOfSync. Can I configure argoCD to map `spec.Duration` to metav1.Duration(kubernetes built-in type)

I couldn't find any known kubernetes built-in types which match metav1.Duration atleast from the well_known types doc that is linked in argoCD docs.
I do not want to add this to ignoreDifferences